# Using SAS formats in Teradata

Tags: sas, teradata, formats

I've been using the SAS 9.3 macro INDTD_PUBLISH_FORMATS to publish formats in Teradata 14. It all works fine, but what I can't see is where the published formats are stored.  The macro creates a series of Teradata functions (SAS_PUTx) that are called when a format is invoked by SAS. Through the external name parameter of the function, there is a path back to the WORK directory on the SAS server and I can see the formats there.  However even when I delete this directory, the formats still work ok. I have no idea where Teradata is storing them. Could it be caching them somewhere? SAS Support seem unable to replicate this behaviour. 
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

%INDTD_PUBLISH_FORMATS macro would have published the format as a UDF on Teradata database. 
Check out ["Overview of the Publishing Process"](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/indbug/64162/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p10m7bigg3hsgbn1f6v5tzjxcyl8.htm).The macro performs the following tasks:

1) creates .h and .c files, which are necessary to build the SAS_PUT() function.

2) produces a script of Teradata commands that are necessary to register the SAS_PUT() function in the Teradata EDW.

3) uses SAS/ACCESS Interface to Teradata to execute the script and publish the files to the Teradata EDW.

You can try using SHOW FUNCTION SAS_PUT on teradata to check the function. Try going through section ["Format Publishing Macro Example"](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/indbug/64162/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p10m7bigg3hsgbn1f6v5tzjxcyl8.htm).

Also, the following link provides information on how the whole publishing thing happens : [SAS(R) 9.3 In-Database Products: User's Guide, Fourth Edition -> How it Works](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/indbug/65980/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p1oqspfeahde3wn1hy3v71cpkhvm.htm)

Hope this helps.

Thanks!